# Skipping a whole test class in xUnit.net

Tags: c#, xunit.net

Is it possible to skip all tests from a specific class like in NUnit

```
[TestFixture]
[Ignore("Reason")]
public class TestClass {
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No - [there is no such facility at present, and the last time it was requested it was considered too low value to add](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/791),

One quick way of achieving the effect in xUnit is to comment out the `public` - private classes are not reflected over (obviously it won't appear on the skip list that way though).

UPDATE: Another way is to put a `TraitAttribute` on the class and then (assuming you're using the `xunit.console` runner) filter it out by running with `/-trait traitName`. (e.g. you can achieve `ExplicitAttribute`, some aspects of the BDD frameworky technique of Pending tests and similar semantics that way - of course the big problem is they don't show up in any reports when using any of these filtering techniques)

UPDATE 2: You can do

```
const string skip = "Class X disabled";

[Fact(Skip=skip)]
void Test() {}
```

Then you can change to to `const string skip = null` to undo the skip. The (dis)advantage of this is that the test is still shown as a Skipped test in the test list, generally with a reason included in the test run report (vs making it `private` which makes it likely to be forgotten)

Comment: With xUnit >= 2.3 you get an error message `error xUnit1000: Test classes must be public`

Comment: Well unfortunately now I see a major use case for this.  Build server has file permissions issues, can only test a suite of tests locally, would be great to easily uncomment a suite of tests in a class locally to run without having to go through many tests to take out "Skip".  Oh well.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my hack to avoid error xUnit1000: Test classes must be public (checked on single Fact, I think Theories can be hacked this way, too).

```cs
// Uncomment to enable tests
//public class FactSwitch : FactAttribute { } // public! ahh, a bug!

// Uncomment to disable tests
internal class FactSwitch : Attribute { }

public class MyTests
{
    [FactSwitch]
    public void MyTest1()
    {
        "it".ShouldBe("it");
    }
}
```

(3 years later)

While searching for the same solution I found there are better ways to do the same.
Let's rewrite the example above in a way Ruben Bartelink suggested (continuation of his idea).

```cs
public class MyTests
{
    //const string SkipOrNot = null; // Run all tests
    const string SkipOrNot = "reason"; // Skip all tests

    [Fact(Skip = SkipOrNot)]
    public void MyTest1()
    {
        "it".ShouldBe("it");
    }
}
```

Nathan Cooper suggested a good improvement for my idea:

```cs
public class MyTests
{
    // Uncomment to disable tests
    //private class FactAttribute : Attribute { }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest1()
    {
        "it".ShouldBe("it");
    }
}
```

So I like both ideas from Ruben and Nathan. There is a subtle difference between using Skip="something" (Ruben) and not using Skip at all. Using "Skip" will put all your tests in a "Skipped tests" warning zone, while "FactAttribute : Attribute" will hide them.

Comment: Using `#define Fact Attribute` is more compact, and would allow you to continue to use `[Fact]`.

Comment: Would be nice shot, but it's not C++, there are limitations for use of #define

Comment: you can also do `const SkipIt = "reason" // change to null to run` and then do `Fact(Skip=SkipIt)` to make it conditional

Comment: Old thread, but you just could put `private class FactAttribute : Attribute { }` inside the class to overpower `[Fact]` because namespaces.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the your class access level as as **internal** and surpress message as @Miq did:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "xUnit1000:Test classes must be public", Justification = "Disabled")]
internal class MyClassThatIsNotATestClass
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the simplest way to dynamically skip a whole xUnit test class at runtime is to use the `TestFrameworkAttribute` at the assembly level, to point to a class that implements the `ITestFramework` interface (or inherits from `XunitTestFramework`, which is simpler) and which overrides the `CreateDiscoverer()` method to return another class, that implements the `ITestFrameworkDiscoverer` interface (or inherits from `XunitTestFrameworkDiscoverer`, which is simpler), where you can finally override the `IsValidTestClass()` method, to decide whether a class should be skipped or not.

Here is some sample code:

```cs
[assembly: TestFramework("MyNamespace.Xunit.MyTestFramework", "MyAssembly")]

namespace MyNamespace.Xunit
{
    public class MyTestFramework : XunitTestFramework
    {
        public MyTestFramework(IMessageSink messageSink)
            : base(messageSink)
        {
        }

        protected override ITestFrameworkDiscoverer CreateDiscoverer(
            IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo)
            => new MyTestFrameworkDiscoverer(
                assemblyInfo,
                SourceInformationProvider,
                DiagnosticMessageSink);
    }

    public class MyTestFrameworkDiscoverer : XunitTestFrameworkDiscoverer
    {
        public MyTestFrameworkDiscoverer(
            IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
            ISourceInformationProvider sourceProvider,
            IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink,
            IXunitTestCollectionFactory collectionFactory = null)
            : base(
                assemblyInfo,
                sourceProvider,
                diagnosticMessageSink,
                collectionFactory)
        {
        }

        protected override bool IsValidTestClass(ITypeInfo type)
            => base.IsValidTestClass(type) &&
               FilterType(type);

        protected virtual bool FilterType(ITypeInfo type)
        {
            // Insert your custom filter conditions here.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with xUnit `2.4.1`.

We are using it in Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (see [AssemblyInfo.cs](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/ebe011a6f1b2a2a9709fe558cfc7ed3215b55c37/test/EFCore.MySql.FunctionalTests/AssemblyInfo.cs#L18-L20) and [MySqlXunitTestFrameworkDiscoverer.cs](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/ade47ba2358e5a8cfbd147db11beb7d64e15b02d/test/EFCore.MySql.FunctionalTests/TestUtilities/Xunit/MySqlXunitTestFrameworkDiscoverer.cs)) (a bit more complex than the sample code here).

Answer (score 3):

I've found yet another way of temporary disabling entire class without compiler warning.

Disabled:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "xUnit1000:Test classes must be public", Justification = "Disabled")]//*/
/*
public /**/class DatabaseTests
{
}
```

to enable move the `/*` one line up (i.e. using alt+up):

```
/*
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "xUnit1000:Test classes must be public", Justification = "Disabled")]//*/
public /**/class DatabaseTests
{
}
```

Note that using full namespace path for SupressMessage does not mess up with your usings.

Answer (score 3):

You can create *LocalOnlyFactAttribute*

```
    public class LocalOnlyFactAttribute : FactAttribute
    {
        //uncomment to run on local
        //const string skip = null; 

        //keep this to avoid slow running tests on other env
        const string skip = "Disabled slow running tests."; 

        public override string Skip { get => skip; set => base.Skip = value; }
    }
```

Comment: base.Skip, not this.Skip or you have stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Here's another hack that requires minimal changes to code

```
using FactAttribute = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute;
using TheoryAttribute = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute;
```

Any compatible attribute can be used for the replacement.

If you also use the `InlineDataAttribute` then you'll need to define a replacement as I don't think there's an existing compatible attribute.

```
using InlineDataAttribute = DummyDataAttribute;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
internal class DummyDataAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DummyDataAttribute(params object[] data)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reason almost after one year after the initial question. I have a set of tests which are calling real server apis, and I would like to run then on demand. With nUnit, it has Ignore attribute : with that set, test runner will skip those tests, but I can still manually run it.

xUnit has no such feature. The nearest one is setting such a class level attribute, and comment it out when I want to run it.

Comment: I believe `ExplicitAttribute` is the name for this. It's still been excluded in a recent discussion for xUnit https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2518

Answer (score 1):

Declaring your class abstract will prevent xUnit from running any tests inside it:

```
abstract MyTestClass {
    // None of the tests inside the abstract class will run
    [Fact]
    public void Test1() {...}
    [Fact]
    public void Test2() {...}
    [Fact]
    public void Test3() {...}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Consider creating *LocalOnlyFactAttribute*, which can be reused across multiple test files.

```
    public class LocalOnlyFactAttribute : FactAttribute
    {
        //uncomment to run on local
        //const string skip = null; 

        //keep this to avoid slow running tests on other env
        const string skip = "Disabled slow running tests."; 

        public override string Skip { get => skip; set => this.Skip = value; }
    }
```